# Future call from apex:component?

Tags: visualforce-component, future

I have 2 Visualforce components inside a main page.
Now the issue is that I need to call a @future method from one of them and I think this is not possible. Every time I get an error:

**System.LimitException: @future call currently not allowed**

This is my future call method:

```
global class TestHelper {
    @future(callout = true)
    public static void syncTest(String dateStr, List<String> feedIdList) {
        System.debug('do something...' + feedIdList);
    }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
public class testctr {
    public void test() {
        TestHelper.syncTest('199', new List<String>{'1', '2'});
    }
}
```

This works:

```
<apex:page controller="testctr">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:commandButton action="{!test}" value="test"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

These don't:

```
<apex:page>
<c:testcmp/>
</apex:page>

<apex:component controller="testctr">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton action = "{!test}" value="test"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Is there any way I can make a future call possible form a component or I have to redesign altogether?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `callout=true`?

Comment: No it doesn't. Gives same error.

Comment: what if you place allowDML="true" in component definition? if you comment callout? does that work?

Comment: if the above doesn't work, pass the outer controller's object as an argument to the component

Comment: allowDML = "true" worked, thanks @kurunve! Please add as an answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @kurunve I added allowDML="true" in the component definition and that worked. I am adding this as an answer to mark this question solved, as I didn't get response from @kurunve to post his comment as answer.